# Can I get first derivative for kernel density estimation in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

I have a data as 2D array and I used `gaussian_kde` to make estimation for data distribution. Now, I want to get the first derivative for the resultant density estimator to get zero crossings. Is it possible to get it from estimated density ?. If so, is there any built-in function in Python that can help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the example in the documentation of the [gaussian_kde](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html), once you have the `Z`, or more generally, the estimation of your density in a X axis, you can calculate its derivatives using standard *numpy* functions:

```
diff = np.gradient(Z)
```

Note that [np.gradient](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) computes central differences. If you would like forward differences you could do something like:

```
diff = np.r_[Z[1:] - Z[:-1], 0]
```

To find the zero-crossings you can do:

```
sdiff = np.sign(diff)
zc = np.where(sdiff[:-1] != sdiff[1:])
```

You can extend the above for 2D as `dy, dx = np.gradient(Z)` with `Z` a 2D array. And then operate in both Y and X direction.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I have couple of questions to update your code on 2d array. For 2d, I should do the following for zero-crossing:
# Zero-crossings
ydiff = np.sign(dy)
zc = np.where([ydiff[:-1] != ydiff[1:]])
or I should do it also for x?. Secondly, If I will use forward/backward difference, should it be xdiff=np.r_[X[1:] - X[:-1], 0] and ydiff = np.r_[Y[1:] - Y[:-1], 0] and in this case zdiff = ydiff/xdiff

Comment: @Carmen First, the answer to the question kind of depends on your goal. For the first one, you should do `Xdiff` aswell. Ydiff will give you derivatives along Y axis (vertical differences) so will also need horizontal differences. For the second question, you don't need zdiff. If you want zero crossings, first calculate zero crossings along X and Y axis separately, and then add them using a `or` logical operator, (this can be done `Zcross = Xcross + Ycross`). You can also get the gradient magnitude which tells you the edge strength as `np.hypot(Xdiff, Ydiff)`.

Comment: If I want to use only the original data instead of the reshaped one. I will have only one dimension result of gaussian_kde which estimated the 3D data. If I get the first derivative of the resultant gaussian_kde, I will have only 1D from first derivative. Is it right to get estimated for 3D as 1D result and get first derivative for it to get at the end the number of peaks ?